# Error when saving value to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm trying to save and read but when I try to save the value of button in the panel, I get error - Unable to set property 'adl' of undefined or null reference. I have never used localStorage before. Can someone help me locate the error?

Thanks

Joe

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" data-semver="2.1.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


    // Save settings

    $( "#myPanel" ).panel({
      beforeopen: function( event, ui ) {}
    });

    $( "#myPanel" ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( event, ui ) {} );


    $( "#myPanel" ).panel({
      close: function( event, ui ) {}
    });

    $( "#myPanel" ).on( "panelclose", function( event, ui ) {
        //localStorage.adl = $("#checkbox-h-2a").is(":checked"); //$('#checkbox-h-2a').val();
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.adl = $("#checkbox-h-2a").is(":checked");
            console.log($("#checkbox-h-2a").is(":checked"));
        }
    });
 });
 </script>
 </head> 
 <body> 

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="overlay">
    <!-- panel content goes here -->
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-h-2a">Auto Detect Location</label>  
  </fieldset>   
</div><!-- /panel -->
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Open Panel</a>     
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">   
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>content will go here</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->     
</div><!-- end of first page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), I don't know what `adl` is but I don't think it's a valid method.

Comment: @user13286 `localStorage.adl = "any value"` should work just fine... https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/t6hkpc4c/

Comment: Adam, I tried your jsfiffle.net code and it didn't work for me. Same error. Tried IE, Firefox and Chrome. adl is just a key.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: IE 11, Firefox and Chrome. Does this code work for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the set method of localStorage like so:

```
localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);
```

Consult the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) for more information.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I get the error - Unable to set property 'adl' of undefined or null reference.

If I comment out
localStorage.adl = $("#checkbox-h-2a").is(":checked");
the line
    console.log($("#checkbox-h-2a").is(":checked"));
outputs true or false based on the check box state correctly. I also tried the following-- var t = $("#checkbox-h-2a").is(":checked");
   localStorage.setItem("adl", t);

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Tried IE 11, Firefox and Chrome. Do I need to change any settings for local storage to work. I'm running the file:///. Will that make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are accessing/ running the html file from your file system, not from any server. That's why you are facing the problem. When you run your web page from **local filesystem**, you can't guarantee that everything works like on webserver.

I was able to replicate your issue in IE-11, when I was accessing the page from file system. Here is the [snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0vQN.png) (please notice the url in the snapshot, it's local file system). I believe you are getting the same error where localStorage is undefined.

Now I am accessing the same html file from simple http server (notice the url in the below screenshot) and it's working fine. Here is the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ5fZ.png) of that where localStorage is not undefined.

So, now that you know your problem, you can run your html page from a server. There are many ways to create a server like using node.js, simple python server etc. I have used simple python server. Hope this solves your issue!